# scrolling window within a css page similar to frames or fixed drop down menu

Tags: php, html, css, encoding, web

I'm not quite sure how to explain it but I've been searching everywhere and to no avail. Please help me here. I took CSS in college but am a bit rusty. I want to have my paleontology site so that I have the dinosaurs names on the left as a scrollable option. My old version of the site was html and it was in frames. People liked the frames cause the main page wasn't affected when they searched for the dinosaur name. In the new css the entire page moves. Also when I add a dinosaur or 3 to the list I don't want to have to add it individually to over 30 pages of dinosaurs. I want to edit one page and have it affect all of them.

I've created an independent page for the dinosaurs -> dino_list.php
But implementing it I'm not sure what to do. I'm guessing there's an "include" code for this?

Can you help me?

Here's the url: http://DinosauriaOnline.com

Thanks,
Vince

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have my paleontology site so that I have the dinosaurs
>   names on the left as a scrollable option.

To make your dinosaur list scrollable, give it an ID such as `#dino-list`, and then use CSS to give it a fixed height. Then set `overflow: scroll` on it in your CSS. That would shrink the list, cutting off some of the content, and then tell the browser that it should have a scrollbar to access the cut-off content.

```
#dino-list {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:200px;
}
```

That produces this:

[image: Dinosaur list, with scrollbar.]

Adding the fixed height is really important - otherwise the browser will assume you want to display the whole list anyway, *and* have a scrollbar.

> Ive created an independant page for the dinosaurs -> dino_list.php But implimenting it im not sure what to do. Im guessing theres an "include" code for this?

Yup.

```
include "dino-list.php";
```

Put this where you want the list. What this does is takes `dino-list.php` and dumps the contents wherever you put that line. So if you have your list as HTML in `dino-list.php`, it'll be placed into the main code wherever you put `include "dino-list.php";`.

So, `dino-list.php` might look like this:

```
<ul id="dino-list">
    <li><a href="Acrocanthosaurus.html">Acrocanthosaurus</a></li>
    <li><a href="Velociraptor.html">Velociraptor</a></li>
</ul>
```

and `index.php` might look like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Dinosaurs</h2>
    <div class="sidemenu">
        <?php include "dino-list.php"; ?>
    </div>
    <h2>Cretacious Non Dinosaurs</h2>
    <!-- rest of sidebar here -->
</div>
```

One thing regarding `include` - it literally takes everything in the source file, and dumps it into your code. If you include PHP code inside `dino-list.php`, it *will* run in your main file.